# Group of equations with bracket and equation numbering

Tags: equations

I have 10 equations which are arranged as shown below. These equations should be arranged in groups of three brackets and aligned. They should be given equation numbering.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this code as the solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\quad Eq. line 1\\
&\quad Eq. line 2\\
&\quad\qquad Eq. line 3\\
&\quad\qquad Eq. line 4\\%[12pt]
&\quad\qquad\qquad Eq. line 5\\
&\quad\qquad\qquad Eq. line 6\\[-.45in]
&\qquad\qquad\left[\begin{array}{l}\mbox{}\\[.13in]\mbox{}\end{array}\right.\nonumber\\
&\quad\qquad Eq. line 7\\
&\quad\qquad Eq. line 8\\[-1.4in]
&\qquad\left[\begin{array}{l}\mbox{}\\[1in]\mbox{}\end{array}\right.\nonumber\\
&\quad Eq. line 9\\
&\quad Eq. line 10\\[-2.2in]
&\left[\begin{array}{l}\mbox{}\\[1.8in]\mbox{}\end{array}\right.\nonumber
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

It can easily be seen that alignment and line spacing problems, and it is not as per the standards of LaTeX typsetting.
Any better solution will be highly appreciable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

spaces and bracket alignments have been improved by the help of multirow package. However equation numbering is still not fixed. Can anyone fixed this problem.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,multirow,bigdelim}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{llll}
\ldelim[{10}{0cm}[] &Eq. line 1\\
                    &Eq. line 2 \\
                    &\begin{array}{lll}
                    \ldelim[{6}{0cm}[] &Eq. line 3\\
                                       &Eq. line 4\\
                                        &\begin{array}{ll}
                                        \ldelim[{2}{0cm}[] &Eq. line 5\\
                                                           &Eq. line 6 \end{array}\\
                                        &Eq. line 7\\
                                        &Eq. line 8\end{array}\\
                    &Eq. line 9\\
                    &Eq. line 10
\end{array}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]